# How to use headers in airflow connection

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have configured a http connection in airflow. I need to provide an x-api-key for authentication so I added this in the "Extra" section.

But the DAG stops with this error:

```
ERROR - Failed to execute job 8 for task get_api_data (Header part ({'x-api-key': '***'}) from ('headers', {'x-api-key': '***'}) must be of type str or bytes, not <class 'dict'>;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In [http.py](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/87f761522e2e80db76c873c8671cd74f8b85e5e8/airflow/providers/http/hooks/http.py#L116) it can be seen that headers are updated directly with contents of "Extra". So you just need to have the following in "Extra" field:

```
{
  "x-api-key": "123456789-038-4662-9d86-123456789"
}
```

(without "headers" key)